# C printf function data formats

Tags: c

Very simple C printing question!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {
   int Age = 0;
   printf("Enter your Age\n");
   scanf("%d",&Age);
   char Name;
   printf("Enter your Full name\n");
   scanf("%s",&Name);
   printf("My name is %s and I am aged %d" ,&Name,Age);
return 0;
}
```

When I input "blah" and `1`, for some reason this returns:
"My name is Blah and I am aged 1929323232"

I presume I am misunderstanding a data format in either the `scanf` or the `printf` functions but can't work it out.

Comment: If you actually inspect the value returned from `scanf()`, you might start to understand the problem.  Oh, and turn on compiler warnings.  You need to reserve space for more than one `char` if you're using `%s`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is because of line

```c
char Name;
```

`Name` is of type `char`. That means that it is supposed to store only one character. As a result
 1. The scanf() is not able to store the input text properly (this will result in a crash in most cases or other undefined behaviour depending on the system *- which judging by the output you provided is what you got*)
 2. (if the code didn't crash) Treating `Name` as a string with the `%s` argument in printf() essentially outputs garbage.

The type that corresponds to strings in C is `char *` (or `char[]`). Essentially, changing `Name` to some statically allocated char-array while performing the necessary changes in the next lines should fix your error:

```c
char Name[256]; //allocated 256 bytes in Name array
printf("Enter your Full name\n");
scanf("%s",Name); // removed & before Name
printf("My name is %s and I am aged %d" ,Name,Age); // same here
```

You could also opt to go with a dynamically allocated string of type `char *` but I guess that's a different topic altogether.

As a general suggestion, I think you should look at pointers more closely. Especially in C, almost all string operations involve being aware of pointer mechanisms.